# Is there a purpose to the room in the back of the inn?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

While waiting for a game to start in the inn, you're free to run around. There is a small hallway under the staircase in the inn that leads to a door. Behind that door is this:

[image: Room in back of inn]

In the picture you can see I circled a ledge that looks like it leads to another part of the inn, but as far as I can tell, it's unreachable. There's a staircase that goes down and leads to some boxes and another door, but that door is not able to open. Is there a purpose to this room? Is there a way up to that ledge? It would seem weird for it to be there if it's for nothing.

Comment: Quite simply: Not yet.